# Склонение собственных имен

Tags: языкознание

Как склоняется фамилия на -а ударное (ШульгА, ДригозА) мужская и женская?

Answer (score 1):

Эти фамилии изменяются по падежам. Как мужская, так и женская.
ШульгИ, ДерезЫ; ШульгЕ, ДерезЕ; - и т.д.
Предыдущий ответ не верен. Женские фамилии славянского происхождения на -А/-Я "склоняются" вне зависимости от места ударения.
Кстати, оговорка насчет согласной перед конечной гласной тоже не имеет большого смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Фамилии явно не французские, перед "а" — согласные. Поэтому мужская склоняется, женская не склоняется.